# Are there any map implementations in Java that will give me a map where the entries are ordered in the same way I put them in?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

What I would like to do is this:

```
for (Entry<Foo, Foo> myEntry : myMap.entryList())
{
    if (someCondition(myEntry.getKey()))
    {
        doSomething(myEntry.getValue())
    }
}
```

The order is important because myEntry.getValue() will point to a key that will be reached later on.  Is there a Map implementation that guarantees the order of the entries and allows me to iterate over the entries in that order?  I found SortedMap, but it looks like SortedMaps sort the keys.  This isn't quite what I need.  I simply want to get my entries out of my map in the same order that I put them in.

For those wondering what I'm trying to do, myMap represents a hierarchy of Foo objects.  When the condition is met in 'someCondition', I mark the parent of the Foo (which happens to be the value of the entry).  Later on when the parent becomes a key, I'll know that I've marked it before and will take action accordingly.  Right now I've created a recursive 'markParent' call, but if I could iterate over the map in a known order, I wouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)? ;-)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the `Map` interface, **with predictable iteration order**. This implementation differs from `HashMap` in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is **normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map** (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map. (A key `k` is reinserted into a map `m` if `m.put(k, v)` is invoked when `m.containsKey(k)` would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

*(My emphasis)*

FWIW, how I got there, to help if you need to find similar information in the future: I had a vague recollection one of the JDK classes did that, so went to [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and read through the list of "Known Implementing Classes." In this case, I knew the name when I saw it, but I figure even if I hadn't known it, `LinkedHashMap` suggests order, so... :-)

Comment: @A4L: LOL I waited to post until I had the link, at least. :-)

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder, nice trick for searching APIs when knowing some base functionality ;-)

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I went down a rabbit hole with the SortedMap. :)

Comment: @JasonThompson: Ooooh, I can see that though... :-)

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashMap will maintain the order of insertion which using LinkedList internally.  And if you want to define any custom order, you can use SortedMap like TreeMap instead.

Comment: Please refrain from adding an already existing answer to the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15369820/2987755, Your answer will be more acceptable if the information is not included.